# Access TextField value from another composable function in by click FloatingActionButt

Tags: android, kotlin, textfield

I have 3 textField in NowyWpisScreen.kt
`
@Composable
fun NowyWpisScreen(vm: MainViewModel) {

```
var iloscLitrow by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf("")
}
var przebytyDystans by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf("")
}
var rachunek by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf("")
}



Column(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()) {
    
    IloscLitrow_TextField(text = iloscLitrow, onValueChange = { string -> iloscLitrow = string })
    PrzejechanyDystans_TextField(text = przebytyDystans, onValueChange = { string -> przebytyDystans = string } )
    CenaPaliwa_TextField(text = rachunek, onValueChange = { string -> rachunek = string } )
}
```

and in file MainScreen.kt i have 2 FloatingActionButton

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    vm: MainViewModel
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val items = listOf(
        BottomNavigationItem.Home
    )
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route


    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(containerColor = TopBarColor),
                title = { Text("Moje Paliwo v2", color = Color.White) })
        },
        bottomBar = {
            NavigationBar() {
                items.forEachIndexed { index, item -> NavigationBarItem(
                    selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                    onClick = {

                        navController.navigate(item.route){
                            navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let{
                                    screent_route -> popUpTo(screent_route){saveState = true}
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
                        selectedIconColor = Nav_SelectedIcon,
                        indicatorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(
                            LocalAbsoluteTonalElevation.current).copy(alpha = 0f)),
                    label = { Text(text = item.label) },
                    alwaysShowLabel = true,
                    icon = {
                        if(currentRoute == item.route) Icon(modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp),
                            imageVector = item.selectedIcon,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                        else Icon(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp),
                            imageVector = item.unselectedIcon,
                            contentDescription = null)
                    }) }
            }
        },
        floatingActionButton = {

            if(currentRoute == BottomNavigationItem.Home.route){
                FloatingActionButton_HOME(navController = navController)
            }
            else if(currentRoute == Destinations.NOWY_WPIS){
                FloatingActionButton_NowyWpis(navController = navController)
            }
        }
    ) {paddingValues ->
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)) {
            Nawigacja(navHostController = navController, vm)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FloatingActionButton_NowyWpis(navController: NavController) {
    ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
        onClick = {

        },
        icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Check, null) },
        text = { Text(text = "Dodaj wpis") },
    )
}

@Composable
fun FloatingActionButton_HOME(navController: NavController) {
    FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
        navController.navigate(Destinations.NOWY_WPIS) {
            navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let{
                    screent_route -> popUpTo(screent_route){saveState = true}
                launchSingleTop = true
                restoreState = true
            }
        }
    },
        shape = CircleShape) {
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = null, tint = Color.Black)
    }
}
```

I want it when clicked in -> FloatingActionButton_NowyWpis after clicking i need this data

```
@Composable
fun NowyWpisScreen(vm: MainViewModel) {


    var iloscLitrow by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    var przebytyDystans by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    var rachunek by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
```

but I do not know how to do it.
Please help,
thanks

I don't know how to solve this, because i want send data by click in FloatingActionButton from another compose function.